# GetElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to getElementById of a certain form but it displays the error

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementById'**

here is my code

```
varForm = document.forms['newform'].getElementById("yellow");
```

Comment: Dom nodes don't have getElementById, that can be used only on document (document.getElementById). If you need something like that try to use .querySelector("#yellow") or .querySelectorAll(".yellow")

Answer (score 2):

an ID is unique -
so there is no difference (you get what you want), calling it directly(/correctly):

```
var Form = document.getElementById("yellow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following way to get input values from another form e.g.

Forms

```
<form id="form1">
    <input id="txt1" type="text" value="111"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input id="txt1" type="text" value="222"/>
</form>
```

Js

```
//get input value from current form i.e. form 1 
alert(document.getElementById("txt1").value)   //111
//get input value from other form i.e. form2
alert(document.forms["form2"].txt1.value)     //222
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, as far as Id is unique we have `getElementById` in `document`:

```
varForm = document.getElementById("yellow");
```

But if you still insist on finding a node based on a specific dom node, you can try:

```
varForm = document.forms['newform'].querySelector("#yellow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as

`Document.querySelector()` and `Document.querySelectorAll()`,

**getElementById()** is **only available** as a method of the **global** **document object**, **and not available** as a method on all element objects in the DOM.

Because **ID** values must be **unique throughout the entire document**, there is no need for "**local**" versions of the function.

So Keep in Your mind about this method:

- it is **called** on the **document** object
- it returns a **single** item

Answer (score 0):

```
var Form = document.getElementById("yellow");
```

this will get your form.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this form:

```
<form id="myform"><input id="lala" type="text" value="123"/></form>
```

There are several ways to get the value of the "lala" input:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("lala").value)
console.log(document.forms[0].lala.value)
console.log(document.forms["myform"].lala.value)
console.log(document.forms.myform.lala.value)
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5q2s/) to play with.